# boost::asio::strand post method performance

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I was measuring the performance from thread A post an event to the strand, until the strand begin to process it. I was presumed that for the different number of receive packets, 500 ,or 1 from the below example, wouldn't impact to the `boost::asio::strand` when it would receive the packets, because **I was just passing the pointer to the packets array `packets_ptr` to the strand**, I believe no copying was involved. However,after I timed 9999999 iteration individually, results shows they aren't even similar between different size. for the size of 1, it always take between 1~9micro sec, and for the size of 500, its bwetween 50 ~85micro sec.

```
//Socket Thread     
int packet_count = recvmmsg(mcast_fd, packets, 500, 0, NULL); //OR
    int packet_count = recvmmsg(mcast_fd, packets, 1, 0, NULL);
    .....
    packets_recv_time = timer.getTime();
    strand_.post(boost::bind(&handler_class::process_package_method, this, packets_ptr, packets_recv_time, num_of_packets));
    .....

//io_service thread
    handler_class::process_package_method(...)
    {
    prcess_beign_time = timer.getTime();
    Measure_time = prcess_beign_time - packets_recv_time;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

The presumptions are correct.  However, the analytics are wrong.  The timestamps are not measuring the performance of [`strand::post()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__strand/post.html).  Instead, they are measuring the duration of when a completion handler is posted into a `strand`, and when the `io_service` starts execution of the completion handler, which is affected by numerous factors (threads, current work load, current `strand` backlog, etc).

To measure the performance of `strand::post()`, one would need to sample immediately before and after the post:

```cpp
auto t1 = clock::now();
strand_.post(...);
auto t2 = clock::now();
```

When a handler is posted into a `strand`, it may be copied or moved before it is executed.  Hence, if a user provided handler's copy/move construction has a uniform cost, then the performance of `strand::post()` will be fairly constant.  Variance can be introduced when:

- The handler's copy/move construction does not have a uniform cost.  For instance, if a `vector` was bound to the handler, then copy construction will be affected by the amount of elements being copied.
- There are multiple threads concurrently changing the `strand`'s internals.  As the `strand` provides thread safety, thread contention may occur within `strand::post()`.

In the original code, the functor returned from `boost::bind()` has the same type regardless of the amount of messages that have been received.  Furthermore, it and its bound arguments have a uniform copy/move construction cost.  Thus, the amount of messages received will not affect the performance of `strand::post()`.

Comment: Hey Tanner, I am appreciate for your detail explanation.  I am actually measuring the performance from thread A post an event to the strand, until the strand begin to process it. Sorry, i was hurry off work yesterday :)